# How to migrate the TFVC projects from Azure DevOps Server to new Azure DevOps account as an Git Repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-repos

I have the TFVC projects in Azure DevOps Server. I want to migrate the TFVC projects from Azure DevOps Server to Git repository in different Azure DevOps organization account.

I have followed [Migrate from TFVC to Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/devops/develop/git/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git) documentation. But it contains the explanation for with in the same account.

Is it possible to migrate the TFVC projects from Azure DevOps Server to new Azure DevOps account as an Git Repository?

Answer (score 0):

As workaround. You can migrate from TFVC to Git on the same Azure DevOps Server. Then mirror your new repo to the new Azure DevOps account: [Move Git repositories to another project with full-fidelity history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/move-git-repos-between-team-projects?view=azure-devops).